# Delphi write to textfile crashing intermittently

Tags: delphi, text-files, delphi-6

I have a program doing massive amounts of calculations in very long loops on a separate thread. To step though this code is going to take forever. For instance in my current problem I am interested in the loops which occur after the 100K iteration. I do not have a specific loop I am interested in and am more interested in a range of loops.

No to combat this I have written the following function:

```
procedure TDLLMainAncestor.printtotext(line:string; name : string = '' );
var
i : integer;
myFile   : TextFile;
begin

 PDebugFilename := IconDescription +'.txt';
  if name <>'' then PDebugFilename := name + '.txt';
  AssignFile(myFile, PDebugFilename);
  if (FileExists(PDebugFilename)) then
      append(myFile)
  else
      ReWrite(myFile);
  Writeln(myFile, line);
  CloseFile(myFile);
end;
```

Now this works. Sometimes. If I call this allot it will crash at random times at random intervals. The thread just stops working. There is no popup error or anything. 
If I remove all the places this is called I get no errors and the thread keeps calculating.

Does anyone have any idea as to why this will cause my thread to kill it self.

Comment: By the way I read this, you are using threads/a DLL.  As far as I'm aware, these procedures aren't thread-safe.  From what I have found in my short research, you would need to set this up in [a Critical Section] (http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showpost.php?s=28c9882ad80b30098b1eed699350dbb6&p=130797&postcount=2).  I have nothing to test this in to put it as an answer, but I hope it helps.

Comment: I do use threads and I call this out of the thread. But I only call this out of the extra thread and not the main GUI thread. The extra thread has a semaphore on it to prevent it from running more one occurrence. So its not possible to call this from multiple places simulations.